# Error when installing ITK with Python bindings

Tags: python, macos, cmake, itk

I'm installing ITK 4.2.2 on OsX 10.8.4.  I built it with CMake 2.8.11.1 using the Unix Makefiles generator.  I'll need the python wrappings, so I selected `ITK_WRAP_PYTHON`.  After I built it, I went to the directory containing the build files in the terminal and entered `make`.  This all went smoothly until I got the following message:

```
[ 41%] Generating vcl_complex.xml
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/climits:50,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_algobase.h:67,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/char_traits.h:46,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/string:47,
                 from /Applications/ITK/src/Modules/Core/Common/include/itkMacro.h:46,
                 from /Applications/ITK/src/Modules/Core/Common/include/itkLightObject.h:21,
                 from /Applications/ITK/src/Modules/Core/Common/include/itkObject.h:31,
                 from /Applications/ITK/src/Modules/Core/Common/include/itkCommand.h:21,
                 from /Applications/ITK/build/Wrapping/Modules/ITKCommon/vcl_complex.cxx:1:
/usr/bin/../lib/clang/4.2/include/limits.h:37:54: error: missing binary operator before token "("
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/postypes.h:49,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/iosfwd:49,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_algobase.h:70,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/char_traits.h:46,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/string:47,
                 from /Applications/ITK/src/Modules/Core/Common/include/itkMacro.h:46,
                 from /Applications/ITK/src/Modules/Core/Common/include/itkLightObject.h:21,
                 from /Applications/ITK/src/Modules/Core/Common/include/itkObject.h:31,
                 from /Applications/ITK/src/Modules/Core/Common/include/itkCommand.h:21,
                 from /Applications/ITK/build/Wrapping/Modules/ITKCommon/vcl_complex.cxx:1:
/usr/bin/../lib/clang/4.2/include/stdint.h:32:54: error: missing binary operator before token "("
make[2]: *** [Wrapping/Modules/ITKCommon/vcl_complex.xml] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Wrapping/Modules/ITKCommon/CMakeFiles/ITKCommonGccXML.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

At this point I wasn't sure if it had "worked," because it had gone from 1% to 100% a number of times in a number of different processes, so I entered `sudo make install`.  After a little while, I got the same error.

**Questions**

1. How do I get rid of this error?
2. Do I need to start the install over again?
3. If I **do** need to start over, is there a way to undo what I've done already first, to get a clean install?

Answer (score 0):

GCC-XML (the tool used in ITK's Python wrapping) does not support the compiler with OSX 10.8 (clang).  This will require support for the Clang-based GCC-XML replacement, CastXML.